# display the properties of an object that is itself in an object array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

Hello I'm trying to display the content of an object on my html page using react. I managed to access the frontend property that are in my object array. Now when I try to browse each element of my frontend object array and display the id of each element on my page it displays only the first element which is "HTML". But I want to display all the other id on the page. I don't know what is the problem

**The external data**

```
const skills = [
  {
    frontend: [
      {
        id: 'HTML',
        img: './images/skills/html5.svg'
      },
      {
        id: 'CSS',
        img: './images/skills/css3.svg'
      },
      {
        id: 'Javascript',
        img: './images/skills/javascript.svg'
      },
      {
        id: 'Bootstrap',
        img: './images/skills/bootstrap.svg'
      },
      {
        id: 'React JS',
        img: './images/skills/react.svg'
      },
      {
        id: 'Flutter',
        img: './images/skills/flutter.svg'
      },
    ],
    backend: [
      {
        id: 'PHP',
        img: './images/skills/php.svg'
      },
      {
        id: '.NET Core',
        img: './images/skills/net-core.svg'
      },
      {
        id: 'Node JS',
        img: './images/skills/html5.svg'
      },
    ],
    languages: [
      {
        id: 'Java',
        img: './images/skills/java.svg'
      },
      {
        id: 'Python',
        img: './images/skills/python.svg'
      },
      {
        id: 'C#',
        img: './images/skills/csharp.svg'
      },
    ],
  },
];

export default skills;
```

**My home file**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "../styles/Home.css";
import Skills from "../data/Skills";

export const Home = () => {
  const [skills, setSkills] = useState([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    setSkills(Skills);
  }, []);

  const frontend = skills.map((element) => {
    return element.frontend;
  });

  console.log(frontend);



  return (
    <div className="home">

      <div className="skills">
        <h1>Skills</h1>

        {frontend.map((item, index) => {
          console.log(index)
          return <ul key={index}>
            <li>{item[index].id}</li>
          </ul>;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[The result is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciKKk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are already importing data, you don't need to store that into a `state`,

Try this ,

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Skills from "./Skills";

export const Home = () => {
  let frontend = [];
  Skills.forEach((skill) => {
    frontend = [...frontend, ...skill.frontend];
  });
  return (
    <div className="home">
      <div className="skills">
        <h1>Skills</h1>
        {frontend.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <ul key={item.id}>
              <li>{item.id}</li>
            </ul>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hi, it works. But I have a function in most of the react tutorials we are told that the data must be put at the state level regardless of the origin of the data. Why do you say that it is not necessary to insert them at the state level once the data has been imported?

Comment: Not necessarily for imported/locally available data, ```state``` is component specific where you will update/delete/insert data. In your case ```data``` that you are importing is ```static```.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Change data file to

```
const skills = {
  frontend: [...],
  backend: [...],
  languages: [...],
};

export default skills;
```

Code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "../styles/Home.css";
import Skills from "../data/Skills";

export const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div className="home">

      <div className="skills">
        <h1>Skills</h1>

        {Skills.frontend.map(item => <ul key={item.id}>
            <li>{item.img}</li>
          </ul>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Or as I understand what you are trying to do, try this

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "../styles/Home.css";
import Skills from "../data/Skills";

export const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div className="home">

      <div className="skills">
        <h1>Skills</h1>

        {Object.keys(Skills).map(skill => <ul key={skill}>
            {Skills[skill].map(item => <li key={item.id}>{item.id}</li>)}
          </ul>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `frontend` is a nested array with only one item, so the index is always 0. The following is the fixed version.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "../styles/Home.css";
import Skills from "../data/Skills";

export const Home = () => {
  const [skills, setSkills] = useState([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    setSkills(Skills);
  }, []);

  const frontend = skills[0].frontend

  console.log(frontend);



  return (
    <div className="home">

      <div className="skills">
        <h1>Skills</h1>

        {frontend.map((item, index) => {
          console.log(index)
          return <ul key={index}>
            <li>{item.id}</li>
          </ul>;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: it displays "skills are undefined" the "useState" is empty while I have already imported the data

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `frontend.map((item, index)` pointed to nested array, the simplest way was like this if you cannot change your backend result:

```
frontend[0].map((item, index)
```